# Angular Mixins integration

Tags: mixins, angularjs

I'm trying to offer a SORT functionality amongst all my modules and I'd like to know integrate this. Does Angular support some sort of mixin?

I'd like the mixin to inject new properties (models) and methods to the controller associated to the module. These properties and methods should only use their associated controller's scope.

I know I could use underscore _.extend or jQuery.extend() , but I'd like to know if there's a cleaner way to do this in a true Angular spirit.

Regards.

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you're trying to accomplish? What exactly is "sort" functionality?

Comment: @Rosarch thanks. I just want a mixin, a service won't do me any good because all variables would be attached to the service, not the controller (or so I think).

What do I want to accomplish? A controller that can inherit the following traits:

- An array to be sorted
- A variable specifying the field to sort
- The direction of the sort (ascending, descending)
- Some other helper functions for adding classes, etc.

Since many controllers will experience the same behaviour I want to include them as a mixin. All of them need these traits in their own scopes as not to poison one another.

Answer (score 1):

**One year later:**

You can use scope inheritance! You can have a main controller with all the functionality you want to share and then you can specify child controllers in the following way:

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="wrapper" ng-controller="SectionCtrl">
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

**MainCtrl:**

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.sorter = { array: [], sort: function() { } };
}
```

**SectionCtrl:**

```
function SectionCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.sorter.array = [1,2,3];
   $scope.sorter.sort();
}
```

No need to declare $scope.sorter since MainCtrl has already declared it. Scope inheritance in angular works pretty much like scope inheritance in Javascript.

Comment: Note, this tightly couples `SectionCtrl` to `MainCtrl`, that is, you cannot use `SectionCtrl` unless it is inside a `MainCtrl`, which makes the component not reusable and it's hard to figure out why it doesn't work when you do try to use SectionCtrl in a different context

Answer (score 1):

Yes! and it is very simple.

I can give you an example how to achieve that:

```
(...)

.controller('ParentCTRL', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.base_func= function() {
        //Do something
    };
}]);

.controller('ChildrenCTRL', ['$controller', '$scope', function($controller, $scope) {

    $controller('ParentCTRL', {$scope: $scope});
    // Now you can access base_fun() from here

}]);

.controller('SecondChildrenCTRL', ['$controller', '$scope', function($controller, $scope) {

    $controller('ParentCTRL', {$scope: $scope});
    // Now you can access base_fun() from here

}]);
```

Comment: This is inheritance, not a mixin? What if you want to mixin two classes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you want a [Service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services), which is then dependency-injected into your controllers and directives.

Comment: Hello Nick. Thanks for replying several years later :P. After learning a lot and coming across this issue time and time again I have found that creating skinny components that communicate with each other is the best way to reuse code and accomplish that sort of mixin functionality that I was looking for. In angular 1 this was a headache, but version 2 is more straight forward and even more so in Areliajs, which is the framework I'm sticking to nowadays.